# Reference other workbook in a formula

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula

I have a workbook named `022315_FNUniverse (2).xlsx` and a sheet named `Regina Import` that I would like to reference in an INDEX formula in Excel. I am unsure how to do so because of the spaces in the names. Both sheets are in the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where names include spaces surround the name in single quotes. Easiest may be to start a formula in one sheet (`=`) and go to the other to select the range you want.

Answer (score 1):

Test it out by using an equals sign, and selecting the corresponding workbook.

An example:

`='[SQL Recursion.xlsm]Sheet  3'!$A$1`